# Why registry class in my controller breaks my page?

Tags: controllers, magento2.2.2, registry

I tried to inject a registry class in my controllers **constructor**, without this registry class, it works **(the `die('Ok')` is displayed )** but when I add the class, it breaks my page, I mean (I have a white page without any error or log) ?

**For More info:** I'm in **developer mode**, the other errors are well displayed but not this one, I don't know if there is really an error or not I don't know !

> `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`
>
> **output**
> `Current application mode: developer. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)`

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    } 

    public function execute()
    {
        die('Ok');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try modifying `protected $_coreRegistry = null;`

Comment: What does log say?

Comment: Can you add more information please. You say it breaks your page, how does it break your page, do you get an error? white page? half a page? anything in your system or exception log?

Comment: @Abhishek Panchal I tried it but i have the same thing

Comment: @Furman  any log or error

Comment: @DanCarlyon any error in page and logs, i just have a white page

Comment: Did you set dev mode? Did you try to kill ./generated/metadata/ and ./generated/code/?

Comment: White page means, that you don't use developer mode. Please pay attention that php bin/magento deploy:mode:show output value can be overriden by environment variables

Comment: @Furman yes Im in developper mode, the other errors are well displayed but not on this one and I don't know if there is really somme error, or i dont know `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show` output `Current application mode: developer. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)`

Comment: @Prince Check app/boostrap.php file. You have to uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I didn't know that it was necessary to regenerate the code,  **empty** the `var/` and `generated/` folders every time we want to **inject classes** into the a **constructor**, and so it solved my problem.

> So we must need to remove the **var** and **generated** content without
>   the  `.htacess`

#### **Why should you regenerate code?**

Suppose a Customer or Proxy class for a Customer class is generated and the Customer class has new methods added to it. Because a Customer or Proxy exists on the file system, it is not regenerated. However, the Customer or Proxy implementation is incomplete now because it does not have the new methods. In this case, you must regenerate the Customer or Proxy class.

If the code generator implementation itself is changed, you must regenerate all the classes. This is rare, however.

More information [here in Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html).